# Get CollectionViewSource Group row?

Tags: wpf, collectionviewsource

I display some date in a WPF ListBox

```
ICollectionView _myView;
_myView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(items);
_myView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("ParentID"));
```

On each group header I need a to display some data about it:

```
 <ListBox.GroupStyle>
  <GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Background="LightBlue">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                      Text="{Binding Path=Name}"  />
          <Button Grid.Column="1" Click="OnShowParentClick"> ShowParent </Button>
        </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
  </GroupStyle>
</ListBox.GroupStyle>
```

How can I get the ParentID associated with the current group?

Angela

Answer (score 0):

here it is:

```
{Binding Path=Items[0].ParentID}
```

just make sure your child objects have ParentID property available. we use it a lot with the commands. 'Items[n].{you property name} opens access to an arbitrary property of an *n'th* child object.

Comment: I need in the OnShowParentClick event, that gets triggered by the button that exist on each group row, to get the ParentID, without having any row selected in the list box. I so not know how to achieve this, still the binding is ok.

Comment: Just use a Command with CommandParameter bound to Path=Items[0].ParentID.